# Querying custom posts and regular posts

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I want to populate the "Greenway News" box on this page with the three latest headlines from the site's Press section AND blog.

The blog is a regular WP blog and I am currently using this code to get my results:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
```

The Press page is a custom post type.  I can get the following code to work as well:

```
<?php
   query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'toolkit' => '2011' ) );
   //the loop start here
   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops

Comment: I've added an answer that assumes you want to show posts and your CPT in the same loop

Answer (score 9):

You're nearly there, you just need to tell WP that you want to query posts as well as your Press CPT.

So:

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => array('posts', 'portfolio'), ...);
```

where portfolio is the name of your custom post type.

The relevant [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

[Update]

So this is how the query should look

```
<?php

  $args = array('post_type'=>array('posts', 'portfolio'));

  query_posts($args);

  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  Yes, I want this in the same loop.   @Anu: I tried following the suggestion.  This is the code I came up with.  `<?php query_posts 
      ( array('post_type' => array('cat=1',  'portfolio', 'Year of Article' => '2011' ) ));
       //loop
       if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>`
     Unfortunately, it only shows the custom post type (Press Articles) not the posts.  http://www.brooklyngreenway.org/?page_id=1037&preview=true    @Anu, did I do something dumb? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but you've added some extra parameters (eg Year of Article) that aren't to do with the original question